# Browser autofill and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a better help :)
I have an input field where my amount is entered. I receive value (string like this '111,00') and I do the following actions:

```
const newVal = value.Amount.toString().replace(/\s/, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
```

then I use custom [validatorjs](https://github.com/skaterdav85/validatorjs)

```
Validator.register('checkSum', value => /^(\d+[.,]|\d*[1-9])\d*$/.test(value));
```

If number zero then the response will be true else false.
But if I want to pass amount from autofill my chrome browser (for example 111,00), I have an error (amount can't be zero) :( I tried to fix this problem with `replace(/\s+/g, '')` but nothing happened and I have the same issue... What I do wrong? And how can I fix this problem?

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:

```
onInputChange: (_, v) => this.handleChange({ Amount: v }),
```

then

```
handleChange(value) {
    const { name } = this.props;
    let onlyAmount;
    if (value.Amount) {
        this.hasComma = value.Amount.toString().indexOf(',') !== -1;
        const newVal = value.Amount.replace(/,/g, '.');
        if (newVal.split('.')[0].length > '9') {
            return false;
        }
        onlyAmount = {
            Amount: newVal,
        };
    }
    this.props.onChange(name, value.Amount ? onlyAmount : value);
}
```

In the componentDidMount

```
this.formValidations.addValidate(`${name}.Amount`, 'checkSum', 'Sum can't be 0');
```

Comment: Please add code where  `value.Amount` is set

Comment: Edit my question

Comment: I'd guess that browser autofill doesn't trigger the handler

Comment: I tested it. And when I choose a value from autofill dropdown, my component invoke handleChange, and I have in `value.Amount` for example `value : { Amount: '111,00' }` .

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a problem yesterday. A chromium added not spaces at all.

```
.replace(/[\u2060]/g, '')
```

It fix my issue.